# WPF ListBox grouping with ExpressionDark theme

Tags: wpf, listbox, grouping, collectionviewsource

I found this simple tutorial on grouping a listbox:

http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2007/06/simple-grouping-in-listbox.html

It works perfectly well, but the application I want to use this in is using the ExpressionDark theme. With this theme enabled, I only see the group headers and not the items.

I can't find out what in the theme is causing this behaviour.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Edit: "Solved" it by using a TreeView instead.

Comment: have you used snoop to inspect the items? also, could you give more information on what exactly you see or see not? maybe post a screenshot

Comment: Like I said; it only shows the group headers. I will try to use Snoop and see what comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: "Solved" it by using a TreeView instead.